# What is the canonical way to implement a global search (that searches throught different resources) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my app searching is a big deal. I have many resources and each search result should pick bits from there and there.

Should I make a search controller?

What's the best architecture in that situation?

*An exmaple use case:*

The user searches for "Eos D5".
The app should reply with a field with the full **product** name, that's constructed out of **manufacturers** name and **product** model. Also if the product is available in neary (to user) shops then he is also told that there is a **shop** he can buy the product from near him. **Manufacturer**'s name for **product** EOS D5 is "Canon".

That makes three models used: **product**, **manufacturer**, **shop**.
The output is something like

> Canon EOS D5

Comment: @user2503775, sorry, I don't understand what code should I attach. I am asking for the best way to write that code, the best (or at least the commonly used) theoretical approach.

Comment: Could you provide more context (schema, use case, limiting factors, etc)? A lot of deciding what to implement comes from the application's design nuances.

Comment: @Jeremiah, updated OP.

Comment: In a case like this, I usually set up a typeahead that routes to a controller action. The controller then calls a custom model function. If you have your ActiveRecord model associations set up well, it should be easy to get the data you want. Since you are searching for a product, I don't see anything wrong with having the search action in your product controller. (If you are going to use a typeahead, twitter typeahead with the bloodhound suggestion engine is the best that I have tried: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/)

Comment: @Jeremiah, should have made an answer!

Answer (score 1):

For complex search functionality I'd recommend using a full-text search engine such as [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

There's a great gem called [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/) that makes integrating with Solr a breeze.

Comment: If you're using postgres, you could also use postgres's built-in text indexing functions, and avoid having to run another server process (Solr). But yes, one way or another, the 'canonical' way to do this -- to have a search that searches accross content stored in multiple tables and columns -- is to use some kind of text indexer, where you index what you want to be searchable. Here's one gem to integrate postgres text search in ActiveRecord, although i'd recommend reading up on the pg feature itself too so you understand what's going on. https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search